lock_pairs and sort_pairs functions, tideman cs50
I’ve been working on tideman (in cs50) and two of my functions have not been working. I thought my project was functioning just fine, but when I ran check50 I got a :( on all the criteria relating to these two functions.
The first is sort_pairs. I decided to just use selection sort because even though it’s slow it seemed like the simplest option:

void sort_pairs(void)
{
    int highest_num = 0;
    int highest_index;
    for (int i = 0, n = pair_count; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = pair_count; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] > highest_num)
            {
                highest_num = preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser];
                highest_index = j;
            }
        }
        swap(pairs, pair_count - i, highest_index);
    }
}

EXPLANATION: the code iterates through all of the pairs (in the inner loop). When it finds a pair with a greater edge than the largest edge previously, it stores that pair’s index in the array in the highest_index variable. At the end of the inner loop, it swaps the highest pair with the last pair in the array (that is still being sorted). Then it iterates again, but shortens the amount of pairs in the array that it’s considering by one, so that it doesn’t keep finding the same highest_number. Here is the (short) code for the swap function I called in this function:

void swap(pair arr[], int index1, int index2)
{
    pair index1_temp = arr[index1];
    pair index2_temp = arr[index2];

    arr[index1] = index2_temp;
    arr[index2] = index1_temp;
}

The next function I am having difficulty with is the lock_pairs function.
int top_person;
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    top_person = pairs[0].winner;
    int losers[candidate_count];
    int loser_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = pair_count; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!is_in(pairs[i].loser, losers, loser_count))
        {
            losers[loser_count] = pairs[i].loser;
            loser_count++;
        }
        if (pairs[i].loser == top_person && !is_in(pairs[i].winner, losers, loser_count))
        {
            losers[loser_count] = top_person;
            loser_count++;
            top_person = pairs[i].winner;
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
        else if (pairs[i].loser != top_person)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}

EXPLANATION: I create a variable called top_person that stores the person who has not been the loser of any locked pairs (yet at least). I define it globally so I can access it in print_winner, and initialize it to the winner of the first sorted pair. I also have an array called losers, which stores all the candidates who have lost a locked pair. For each pair, I add the loser to an array called losers (note: I also have a variable called loser_count so I know what index to add the losers to in the losers array). If the loser of the pair that the loop is on is the current top_person, the program first checks is the winner of the pair is in the losers array (using a function I defined, which I’ll add below). If the winner of that pair isn’t in the losers array, it locks in the pair and adds the old top_person to the losers array. If the loser of the pair isn’t the top person, it just automatically locks in the pair (because even if it creates a cycle it won’t effect the top_person).
Here’s my (very simple) is_in function:
bool is_in(int num, int arr[], int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

I know that this post is a lot, so thank you so much to anyone who took the time to read it! Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT: sorry guys, I Had assumed people would be familiar with this assignment but that is not the case. First, I should explain the nature of this problem:
This problem simulates a way of voting called “tideman voting”. Here, instead of voting for one candidate, voters rank all candidates from beat to worst. To find who won, you must first tally up how many times each voter was preferred over another, in order of how many people preferred them. You only keep track of how many times they were preferred over someone if they were preferred over that person more times than that person was preferred over them. If there is a tie, you don’t put it down on your list.
This is where it gets a little tricky. You want to create a map of sorts with all the candidates, and starting with your first pair (remember that the pairs are in order of strength of victory), you “lock in” that edge. You can imagine this as an arrow pointing from the winner of the pair to the loser. The catch here, though, is that you don’t want to create any cycles (a place where the “arrows” make a circle and no one comes out on top”). If a pair creates a cycle, skip it. In the end, the winner is the person with no “arrows” pointing at them (in other words, the winner is the one who didn’t lose any pairs that got locked in).
Now, allow me to explain what my functions are supposed to do:

Sort_pairs takes an array of data type pair, which is a data structure defined earlier in the code. Pairs contain two variables: winner and loser. In this code, there is also a 2D array of Ints called preferences. Preferences[a][b] res presents the number of people who prefer a over b. Sort_pairs is supposed to sort all the pairs in the pair array by strength of victory (aka what preferences[winner][loser] is). Note that winner, loser, and indexes of preferences are ints, but those ints are just indexes of a specific person’s name in a different array, but that isn’t very important for this part of the problem.
Lock_pairs is a bit more complicated. You need to go through the now sorted pairs and lock them in one by one into the Boolean 2D “locked” array, where locked[i][j] represents whether or not I has been “locked” in over j. Like I explained before, if locking a pair into the array creates a cycle where no one is on top, you must skip that pair without locking it in.


It might help if you tell us what your functions are supposed to do. With what data with what outcome. You do not provide most of the definitions you are using. What edges are you talking about? What pairs? Also, check50 normally tells a bit about the test that failed. Don't you get any test data from there with what data your function fails?

PLease edit your question to include a MCVE; together with as much test data as possible.

Not directly relevant to your question, but you're obviously using global variables. It's better to avoid this. In this case, if you were passing things like pairs via arguments to your functions, we could evaluate the functions independently. Oddly, you have done this with your swap function. Though that might be implemented just using a pair of pair pointers.

Does pair_count fall within the range of valid indices for the pair array? Because in sort_pairs, j = pair_count for the first iteration that accesses pair[j]. Also, is it possible for highest_index to never be assigned to in the inner loop of sort_pairs? Because the swap would be invalid if highest_index is not assigned to.

Although the advice on avoiding using global variables is generally good, I suggest that you ignore this advice for this assignment, because this assignment requires you to use the global variables provided by the distribution code.

Have a look at Related questions links on this page. Also, you may find reading though comments on CS50 Tideman: lock_pairs not correctly locking all non-cyclical pairs despite appearing correct helpful. And lastly, search in the box at top "[cs50] tideman lock pairs" for many more related questions. The key is to read closely the Tally:, Sort: and Lock: details as explained in the CS50 question. When sorted in decreasing order of strength, then iterating in-order to lock -- which is the only iteration a cycle can occur on?

Also, C provides qsort() to sort arrays (collections) of anything. You simply need to learn to write the compare() function you pass to qsort() to tell it how you want things sorted. Then sorting any collection with qsort() is a single line of code (and the sort algorithm has had decades of verification). Example provided by link in comments in link above. The compare function simply takes pointers to elements of the array to be sorted and returns less than 0 if the 1st sorts before the 2nd, 0 if equal, a positive value otherwise.
